# Data not posted in redis while the redis connected successfully

Tags: php, redis, node-modules, node-redis

I have installed redis,I can execute commands on redis-cli & node gives success message on redis connection but there is problem in data insert in redis & when I connect to my other server's redish to node it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Find notify-keyspace-events and replace it with :

```
notify-keyspace-events "KEA"
```

Restart Redis Server